# How do I specify the location of where I want to add a table in a MS Word Document

Tags: python, python-docx

I am generating a word document using python doc.add_table method. The table is automatically generated at the end of the word document. How do I specify where this table should be added within the document?

I have tried using various alignment methods but none have worked so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

let's assume that you have a document `t1.docx` like:

[image]

and that you want to insert table between paragraphs 2 and 3. you can do so by:

```py
from docx import Document

doc = Document('t1.docx')

# the table you want to insert at position
tbl = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=2) # actually inserts table at the bottom of the document, but we'll move it to the target location
tbl.style = 'Table Grid'
row = tbl.rows[0]
row.cells[0].text = 'hey'
row.cells[1].text = 'hoo'
tbl_el = tbl._element

# find target place to move table to
target_el = None
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    if p.text == 'Paragraph 2':
        target_el = p._element


# insert after the target element (actually moves existing element to that location)
parent_el = target_el.getparent()
parent_el.insert(parent_el.index(target_el)+1, tbl_el)

doc.save('t2.docx')
```

and there you have it the end `t2.docx`:

[image]